# VeReMi veins 4.6 attacker app rapidjaon on windows

Tags: omnet++, rapidjson

So basically I'm using veins 4.6 for running this attacker app https://github.com/VeReMi-dataset/veins/tree/securecomm2018/src/veins/modules/application/attackerapp but in Windows now I have a problem regarding the rapid Jason

*1) the full path where you have unpacked RapidJson;
This is my path*

C:\Users\Murad\Desktop\rapidjson\include

*2) the content of make frag from the src directory of your veins;*
[enter image description here][1]
**#

*3) detailed error message*
these are the photos
https://drive.google.com/file/d/11ln1ooG6bO9oG0-RwchaRrkw95wWo2pF/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AZZfYsUbZMIYWqtpAII7alKK7PBGp7xi/view?usp=sharing
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZnO2.png

Comment: the problem is that the lib not included to my environment

Comment: There is no "lib".  RapidJSON is entirely in the includes files.  EXACTLY what problem do you have?  What are the error messages?  You are expecting us to read your mind.  "Not work" tells us nothing at all.

Comment: the error is the following: unresolved inclusion and i dont know how i can solve this #include "rapidjson/writer.h"
#include "rapidjson/stringbuffer.h"
#include "rapidjson/document.h"

Comment: Show us the `Makefile.inc` (unless it is too large).  Don't hide the path, like you did above.  And please edit the question to include it.  Don't make a huge comment.

Comment: Yes, that's what I expected.  Do you notice how that differs from what you have in the example above?  You need to stop your path at `...\include`.  The source files all put the `"rapidjson"` part in their #include lines.

Comment: the same problem

Comment: can we meet in Anydesk and you help me?

Comment: What command are you running to build this?

Comment: please check my question again

Answer (score 1):

`OMNeT++` project usually uses Makefile that is generated automatically and it mustn't be edited manually. Try to add the include directory of `Rapid JSON` using  `Makefrag`.
Let's assume that one unpacked `Rapid JSON` into the following directory:

```
C:\Users\Murad\Desktop\rapidjson\include
```

i.e. there is the file `C:\Users\Murad\Desktop\rapidjson\include\rapidjson\stringbuffer.h`

There are two ways of editing `makefrag`:

- Method 1:
  Go to `Project Properties`, choose `OMNeT++` | `Makemake` | select `src` | `Options` | `Custom` | `Makefrag` and write:

  ```
  INCLUDE_PATH += -I/c/Users/Murad/Desktop/rapidjson/include
  ```
- Method 2:
  Open in any text editor `makefrag` from `veins\src` and add the above mentioned line with `INCLUDE_PATH`.

Note that `/c/` means `C:\`.
Then use in your code:

```
#include "rapidjson/stringbuffer.h"
```

Comment: my files in veins so i wrote this in veins --> scr--> application.

Comment: Jerzy d can i share my screen with you using team viewer or Anydesk ?

Comment: Could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77041174/edit) the question and write: 1) the full path where you have unpacked RapidJson; 2) the content of `makefrag` from `src` directory of your `veins`; 3) detailed error message.

Comment: SURE I WILL DO IY

Comment: please check my question again

Comment: The path in `INCLUDE_PATH` **must** reflect the path where `rapidjson` directory exists with `stringbuffer.h` inside. By the way: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You mean the path should included the files write and string buffer also? ?

Comment: No, write just `INCLUDE_PATH += -I/c/Users/Murad/Desktop/rapidjson/include`.

Comment: its the same .. as i mention in the pictures below

Comment: #
# OMNeT++/OMNEST Makefile for $(LIB_PREFIX)veins
#
# This file was generated with the command:
#  opp_makemake --make-so -f --deep -o veins -O out -I/c/Users/Murad/Desktop/rapidjson/include -I.
#

# Name of target to be created (-o option)
TARGET = $(LIB_PREFIX)veins$(D)$(SHARED_LIB_SUFFIX)
TARGET_DIR = .

# C++ include paths (with -I)
INCLUDE_PATH = -I/c/Users/Murad/Desktop/rapidjson/include -I.

# Additional object and library files to link with
EXTRA_OBJS =

# Additional libraries (-L, -l options)

Comment: how can i share my screen with you?

Comment: you are an expert i want to show you my screen and you can help me  still facing the same issues

Comment: In Stackoverflow we help _publicly_. I suggest edit your question and provide [mcve] - i.e. describe how to get the project you are trying to build, describe version of OS, OMNeT++, show errors as a text etc.

Comment: i have seen that you have the experience did you have any accounts in linkedin , or any telegram .. i want to show you my files  please

Comment: im new in this platform.. any platform { fiver , telegram any thing}